# Preventing override of methods in Objective-C

Tags: coding-style, coding-standards, objective-c

Objective-C lacks private methods or java-esque final methods.  This means that it is possible for a subclass to (accidentally) override some of the internals of a superclass.

How does one prevent overriding methods in Objective-C?

Comment: This will be closed if you don't add further explanation. This really shows no effort on your part and doesn't frame the question in a way which it could be answered beneficially.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172598/best-way-to-define-private-methods-for-a-class-in-objective-c

Answer (score 7):

> How does one prevent overriding methods in Objective-C?

You write in the documentation for your class something like:

> *Subclasses should not override this method.*

Seriously. I copied that quote straight from the documentation for UIView.

Objective-C encourages a culture of doing by convention many things which would be enforced by a compiler in other languages, and this is one of those things. I'm sure you could play some games in with the runtime whereby you get the IMP for the method you're about to call and compare it to the IMP of your own class's method. But then, it's possible that someone might swizzle an is-a on you, or otherwise play their own games, and in the end it's usually best to just say "Please don't do that."

Comment: +1, The only possible correct answer. It is up to you to indicate you don't want something overriden. And it is up to the client of your code to suffer the consequences of ignoring your warnings.

Comment: From [Why doesn't objective c support private methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158660/why-doesnt-objective-c-support-private-methods) - [one comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158660/why-doesnt-objective-c-support-private-methods#comment2102979_2159027) starts out "Objective-C is (in some ways) a "big-boy" language in which programmers are expected to exhibit a certain amount of discipline, rather than getting slapped on the hand by the compiler/runtime at every turn."

Comment: @MichaelT: That's an interesting sentiment, but I still find things like `private` and `sealed` in the C# compiler to be very useful as first-class constructs of the language. Real programmers write everything in assembler anyway, with all the safeties off.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I absolutely agree.  I find sealed jars and final classes or methods to be a very useful construct in enforcing the developer's ideal.  Other languages are more code by convention and "don't stick your fingers here or things can go wrong" without having any way to enforce it. Its a trade off.